# Hibernate Criteria Restrictions: comparing two properties as simple expression

Tags: hibernate, criteria, restrictions

I have a Hibernate Criteria, for which the following works:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("x", "tbl.y"));
```

but I now want to modify the criteria to check a range of possible values ('x' and 'y' are both integers), for example, this doesn't work:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.geProperty("x", "tbl.y - 1"));
```

I've tried using an sqlRestriction, such as:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.x >= (tbl1_.y - 1)"));
```

but how to know the actual alias name ('tbl1_') ?

Am I going to have to use a subselect to make this work? (Using HQL is not a practical option right now.)

Comment: `Restrictions.eqProperty("x", "y")` : x and y should be property names. Your question is not clear. What is your objective?

Comment: Wow. I did put effort into making the question clear. Not sure what I missed. Instead of 'where x = y', I want 'where x >= (y - 1)'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
criteria.add(new PropertyExpression(null, null, null) {
    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        String x = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, "x")[0];
        String y = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, "tbl.y")[0];
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append(x);
        result.append(">= (");
        result.append(y);
        result.append(" - 1)");
        return result.toString();
    }
});
```

shame there's no way, using Hibernate Criteria API, to do this (alias a joined table):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.x >= ({tbl}.y - 1)"));
```

Comment: Agreed. I was frustrated by this too, so ended up opening a pull request for it: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/533/files. Something like this works in the meantime, though :). Thanks for posting your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own Criterion implementation for this:

```
public static class YourCriterion implements Criterion{

    @Override
    public TypedValue[] getTypedValues(Criteria arg0, CriteriaQuery arg1) throws HibernateException {
        return new TypedValue[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
        String x = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, "x")[0];
        String y = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, "tbl.y")[0];
         StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
         query.append(x);
         query.append(">= (");
         query.append(y);
         query.append(" - 1)");
         return query.toString();
    }

}
 criteria.add(new YourCriterion());
```

For reference: [PropertyExpression](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.4.Final/org/hibernate/criterion/PropertyExpression.java#PropertyExpression)